# How can I improve that kind of answers?

Tags: discussion, answers, quality-improvement

Here is a question which can be easily answered with little research.

**Q:** [How to include a Double Variable in a String Variable in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26957359/3453226)

Answers just give the solution.

**A:** [Joiner's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26957411/3453226)

- *"You can use"*.
- Link.
- Sample code.

How can I improve that kind of answers?

Comment: I don't see a particular problem with the answer. What is it that bothers you about it?

Comment: It has a great more upvoted answer as example

Comment: @Bart It is a link-only answer.

Comment: @rene Could not understand you.

Comment: Not it's not. Link-only is "You can find your answer here" with the text being a link. This answer states what the OP could use, where to find the documentation for it, as well as provides an example of how to use it.

Comment: @Bart I got tired of these answers. I am going to hate the _"You can use"_ three words, so I am looking for some suggestions.

Comment: [DasBlinkenLight](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26957412/578411) provided a much better/detailed/elaborated answer than yours. Take that as an example. I wouldn't be surprised if that will get the most upvotes in the end, despite your answer being accepted.

Comment: Why are you asking this question?

Comment: @Joiner if you're tired of these answers, you could stop answering these types of questions.

Comment: @l4mpi No, I could open a discussion on Meta, like [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276985/3453226).

Comment: Are you just asking why you didn't get upvotes? The answer was fine; but the other answer caught the "150 variables" piece in the question (which wasn't what was asked, but was good advice in addition to answering the question). I don't understand what you are looking for here.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET No, I am not. However, I got `+1` and then `-1`.

Comment: I wouldn't have downvoted it. Without a comment; we can never know what they were thinking.

Comment: @Joiner. ok!? I asked you a relevant question, you started talking about cats. -1 for a pointless question. You can tell it's pointless by the lack of answers.